# Java selenium - skip span element within div

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

Here's my `html` structure and I am trying to skip a `span` within a `div` to get div's text only (which is dynamic) for testing.

```
<div class="items">
   <div class="payment void" id="payment-000000899799">
      <div class="payment__details">
         <div class="method">CASH <span class="label"><span>Payment Voided</span></span></div>
         <div class="date">2/12/2021, 3:02:15 PM</div>
      </div>
      <div class="payment__details">
         <div class="amount">$20.00</div>
         <div class="ref">Ref ID: REF-ID-01</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="payment sale" id="payment-000000899806">
      <div class="payment__details">
         <div class="method">CASH </div>
         <div class="date">2/12/2021, 3:02:21 PM</div>
      </div>
      <div class="payment__details">
         <div class="amount">$100.00</div>
         <div class="ref">Ref ID: REF-ID-02</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my step definition I've

```
List<List<String>> data = capturedData.raw();        
WebElement paymentDetails = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='payment__details']/div[@class='method'])[" + data.get(1).get(0) + "]"));
    
    String paymentType = paymentDetails.getText();
    System.out.println(paymentType); //This prints CASH Payment Voided
```

But actually I want only 'CASH' which is a text of `div` and skip the text 'Payment Voided' of `span`. And `data` is coming from a feature file.

**How do I get text of `div` only and skip the text `span` which is inside the same `div`?**

Comment: Is it easier to get booth <div class="method">CASH and then just from list choose, the second one, using find elements.

Comment: element.getAttribute("outerHTML") is what your looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot skip it directly since it is part of element.

**1st Approach**

```
String fulltext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='payment__details']/div[@class='method'][1]")).getText();
String spantext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='payment__details']/div[@class='method'][1]/span")).getText();
//Now replace span text with ""    
String output = fulltext.replace(span,"");
```

**2nd Approach**

```
 WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='payment__details']/div[@class='method'][1]"));
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String output = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent",parent);
```